# How to run Jenkins build on selected snapshot which is uploaded on Artifactory

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory, devops

I have 2 Jenkins job - Build, Run.

- Build job is checking out code from Git, building it and deploy snapshot to Artifactory (using `mvn deploy` in shell script).
- In Run job, person who is running the job should be able to select snapshot version deployed in first job and run test scripts against it. Deployed snapshot version will be available in Artifactory repo.

How can I configure my Run job in Jenkins?

**Note**: Its Maven Java project. In Git, it will checkout a folder which will have sub folders. One subfolder will have code which is used in build job and other subfolder will have code to invoke test cases in previous folder.

e.g.

```
cd ${WORKSPACE}/mybuildsubFolder
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
cd ${WORKSPACE}/myrunsubFolder
mvn clean install -P abc-Dformat.type=xyz
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly should the "person" do in the Run job?

Comment: @JFMeier : person who will trigger Run job will select a snapshot version from all the snapshots available in Artifactory repository and run the script mvn clean install -P abc-Dformat.type=xyz.  Snapshot versions are uploaded in repository by Build job which can be triggered independently and will build/deploy snapshot when required.

Comment: This sounds simply wrong, cause a sub folder which contains the code and one which contains the tests? Why not running the tests with one go ...it's easier and consistent..without manually selecting some kind of versions? Whoever knows which SNAPSHOT versions belong to the particular code state ?

Comment: As @khmarbaise said: It does not make sense to choose an artifact to test if the loaded tests belong to a specific build. Why not just run the tests on the built artifact?

Comment: I am sorry if I created confusion here. When I say running test, that doesn't mean junit or any test part of the code in build folder. End user for this snapshot built will be testers who can download this as dependency in their project from Artifactory.  So it is segregated in 2 folders. Thats the reason it is segregated in different folders but both these have their own pom.xml and independent.

Comment: A jar dependency is usually used by developers...you should run your tests on a CI solution makes it easier....and reduces problems to find which issue is related to which version => git state etc.